# primefaces schedule with parameter in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, backing-beans

Hello I am here to ask  your help following a  difficult i meet in my project .Your different point of vue are welcome.
I am using primefaces Schedule to perform a given task but I don't know how
I can pass a parameter to my backing bean.I would like to use this parameter in backing bean when a schedule event triggered like SelectEvent or dateSelect . For example if I have a parameter **personeID** I would pass this 
parameter to the bean so that when actionListener will activate this 
setting can be initialized in the bean so that I can use.
that my code

```
<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{inscrireAgendaBean.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule"  process="@form" axisFormat="HH:mm"  columnFormat="dddd D/MM" firstHour="08" locale="fr" timeZone="GMT+1"  timeFormat="HH:mm">

  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{inscrireAgendaBean.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />

  <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{inscrireAgendaBean.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />

 </p:schedule>
```

I just want to know if there is a possibility to add a parameter to my bean  when eventSelect or dateSelect triggered
Thank you !!!

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? this is pretty covered over there

Comment: yes i have read the primefaces user guide but i have not  found it there. So if you have any idea for me it could help me too.

Comment: Okay you need to elaborate more to get some answers here :) you can start here for example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml line 171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from your question that you want to triger a listener when you select an event, so you have to add a `p:ajax` with a `eventSelect` event :

```
<p:schedule id="scheduleLocale"  value="#{managedBean.schedule}" draggable="false" resizable="false" axisFormat="HH:mm"  columnFormat="dddd D/MM" firstHour="08" locale="fr" timeZone="GMT+1"  timeFormat="HH:mm" >
    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
</p:schedule>
```

and on you managedBean the `onEventSelect` method will be as follows:

```
public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
}
```

so `getObject()` will allow you to retrieve informations like **personeID**, and depends if you actually put **personelID** when you first created the event with `event = new DefaultScheduleEvent()`

to add an event by selecting a date on a schedule, you use `p:ajax` with `dateSelect` event:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
```

this will show up a dialog, you can put any information you want to add to the event, the user will enter it, so no need to pass any parameters.

Comment: Thank you for replying but i have edited my question to permit any one who want to help me to understand it.Thank you!!

Comment: @SANDWIDI i guess this answers your question

Comment: i think that eventSelect supposes that you have already created an event in your shedule. For my case here i want to pass parameter to my bean when create new event in my schedule.Thank you.

Comment: it's the same thing whether it was already created or when you create a new one!!!

Comment: you use the same expression new DefaultScheduleEvent(*****)

Comment: okay i understand what you say but i want to pass the id of person who creates the event in schedule like a parameter how can i proceed? I need your help.In this case i can find different events created by different persons.

Comment: the id of the user should not be passed as parameter, your system should save the current user the moment when he login, so when you create an event its logicaly the current user who created it

Comment: Thank you ,in my project i have an user saved in session but before creating event in schedule the current user opens a dialog after choosing a space.My purpose is to pass the id of space as parameter choosed by the user when he opens the dialog to create events.
How can i proceed to pass the parameter of space to my bean not the current user'id saved in session?